# Inserting a line break in a SQL string based on a specific interval/character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got the following string of field names:

```
'TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [TPSYN]) AS [TPSYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [SureFitYN]) AS [SureFitYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], Convert(VarChar(250), [Account Name]) AS [Account Name], Convert(VarChar(250), [EffectiveDate]) AS [EffectiveDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [IM]) AS [IM], Convert(VarChar(250), [RevisionDate]) AS [RevisionDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountAddress]) AS [AccountAddress], Convert(VarChar(250), [LSOCode]) AS [LSOCode], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASONonASOBoth]) AS [ASONonASOBoth], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedicalYN]) AS [MedicalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [NonManagedCareYN]) AS [NonManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ManagedCareYN]) AS [ManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HRAYN]) AS [HRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedHRAYN]) AS [MedHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [LPHRAYN]) AS [LPHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthyFutYN]) AS [HealthyFutYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HAHRAYN]) AS [HAHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HSAYN]) AS [HSAYN], Convert(VarChar(25
0), [FSAHealthCare]) AS [FSAHealthCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSADependentCare]) AS [FSADependentCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [DentalYN]) AS [DentalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [TaftHartley]) AS [TaftHartley], Convert(VarChar(250), [ParameterComments]) AS [ParameterComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContact]) AS [MLRContact], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress1]) AS [MLRContactAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress2]) AS [MLRContactAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactCity]) AS [MLRContactCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactState]) AS [MLRContactState], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactZip]) AS [MLRContactZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthRiskAssessment]) AS [HealthRiskAssessment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaYN]) AS [ErisaYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanName]) AS [ErisaPlanName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanNumber]) AS [ErisaPlanNum
ber], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaAdministrator]) AS [ErisaAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaClaimAdministrator]) AS [ErisaClaimAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaCost]) AS [ErisaCost], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOB]) AS [ErisaEOB], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBName]) AS [ErisaEOBName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress1]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress2]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBCity]) AS [ErisaEOBCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBState]) AS [ErisaEOBState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBZip]) AS [ErisaEOBZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBPhone]) AS [ErisaEOBPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAName]) AS [ErisaPAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress1]) AS [ErisaPAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress2]) AS [ErisaPAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPACity]) AS [Eris
aPACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAState]) AS [ErisaPAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAZip]) AS [ErisaPAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAPhone]) AS [ErisaPAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAName]) AS [ErisaLAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress1]) AS [ErisaLAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress2]) AS [ErisaLAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLACity]) AS [ErisaLACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAState]) AS [ErisaLAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAZip]) AS [ErisaLAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAPhone]) AS [ErisaLAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ERISAComments]) AS [ERISAComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNApproval]) AS [CSNApproval], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNPPO]) AS [CSNPPO], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOAP]) AS [CSNOAP], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNSupplemental]) AS [CSNSupplemental], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNReplacement]) AS [CSNReplacement], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNType]) AS [CSNType], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNIL915]) AS [CSNNBNIL915], Convert(VarCh
ar(250), [CSNNBNPA910]) AS [CSNNBNPA910], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA911]) AS [CSNNBNPA911], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNFL918]) AS [CSNNBNFL918], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNCA915]) AS [CSNNBNCA915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNMA904]) AS [CSNNBNMA904], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOwnLogo]) AS [CSNOwnLogo], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNAllBranches]) AS [CSNNBNAllBranches], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNBranchComment]) AS [CSNNBNBranchComment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOStopLoss]) AS [ASOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOCigna]) AS [ASOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOThirdParty]) AS [ASOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASORetirees]) AS [ASORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOStopLoss]) AS [ISOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOCigna]) AS [ISOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOThirdParty]) AS [ISOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISORetirees]) AS [ISORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbCigna]) AS [ASOReimbCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbOther]) AS [ASOReimbOther]'
```

What I need to do is insert line breaks so that no line is more than 950 characters long, but I need to insert those breaks at the end of a field name.  So, what I need to do is start at character 950 and work backwards until I find the first instance of "],".  I need to insert the line break there, then count forward 950 characters and again work backwards until I hit the first instance of "],".  Lather, rinse, repeat.

The resulting string should end up looking something like this (unless I counted wrong):

```
TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [TPSYN]) AS [TPSYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [SureFitYN]) AS [SureFitYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], Convert(VarChar(250), [Account Name]) AS [Account Name], Convert(VarChar(250), [EffectiveDate]) AS [EffectiveDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [IM]) AS [IM], Convert(VarChar(250), [RevisionDate]) AS [RevisionDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountAddress]) AS [AccountAddress], Convert(VarChar(250), [LSOCode]) AS [LSOCode], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASONonASOBoth]) AS [ASONonASOBoth], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedicalYN]) AS [MedicalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [NonManagedCareYN]) AS [NonManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ManagedCareYN]) AS [ManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HRAYN]) AS [HRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedHRAYN]) AS [MedHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [LPHRAYN]) AS [LPHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthyFutYN]) AS [HealthyFutYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HAHRAYN]) AS [HAHRAYN], 
Convert(VarChar(250), [HSAYN]) AS [HSAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSAHealthCare]) AS [FSAHealthCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSADependentCare]) AS [FSADependentCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [DentalYN]) AS [DentalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [TaftHartley]) AS [TaftHartley], Convert(VarChar(250), [ParameterComments]) AS [ParameterComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContact]) AS [MLRContact], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress1]) AS [MLRContactAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress2]) AS [MLRContactAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactCity]) AS [MLRContactCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactState]) AS [MLRContactState], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactZip]) AS [MLRContactZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthRiskAssessment]) AS [HealthRiskAssessment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaYN]) AS [ErisaYN], 
Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanName]) AS [ErisaPlanName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanNumber]) AS [ErisaPlanNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaAdministrator]) AS [ErisaAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaClaimAdministrator]) AS [ErisaClaimAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaCost]) AS [ErisaCost], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOB]) AS [ErisaEOB], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBName]) AS [ErisaEOBName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress1]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress2]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBCity]) AS [ErisaEOBCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBState]) AS [ErisaEOBState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBZip]) AS [ErisaEOBZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBPhone]) AS [ErisaEOBPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAName]) AS [ErisaPAName], 
Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress1]) AS [ErisaPAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress2]) AS [ErisaPAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPACity]) AS [ErisaPACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAState]) AS [ErisaPAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAZip]) AS [ErisaPAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAPhone]) AS [ErisaPAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAName]) AS [ErisaLAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress1]) AS [ErisaLAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress2]) AS [ErisaLAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLACity]) AS [ErisaLACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAState]) AS [ErisaLAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAZip]) AS [ErisaLAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAPhone]) AS [ErisaLAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ERISAComments]) AS [ERISAComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNApproval]) AS [CSNApproval], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNPPO]) AS [CSNPPO], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOAP]) AS [CSNOAP], 
Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNSupplemental]) AS [CSNSupplemental], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNReplacement]) AS [CSNReplacement], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNType]) AS [CSNType], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNIL915]) AS [CSNNBNIL915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA910]) AS [CSNNBNPA910], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA911]) AS [CSNNBNPA911], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNFL918]) AS [CSNNBNFL918], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNCA915]) AS [CSNNBNCA915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNMA904]) AS [CSNNBNMA904], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOwnLogo]) AS [CSNOwnLogo], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNAllBranches]) AS [CSNNBNAllBranches], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNBranchComment]) AS [CSNNBNBranchComment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOStopLoss]) AS [ASOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOCigna]) AS [ASOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOThirdParty]) AS [ASOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASORetirees]) AS [ASORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOStopLoss]) AS [ISOStopLoss], 
Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOCigna]) AS [ISOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOThirdParty]) AS [ISOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISORetirees]) AS [ISORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbCigna]) AS [ASOReimbCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbOther]) AS [ASOReimbOther]
```

The string will almost always be changing, so I can't hard code the breaks, it's got to be dynamically done.

I know a little SQL but not enough to do this, I don't even know where to start.

Someone gave me this code, but all it does is insert a line break after the first 950 characters:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [TPSYN]) AS [TPSYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [SureFitYN]) AS [SureFitYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], Convert(VarChar(250), [Account Name]) AS [Account Name], Convert(VarChar(250), [EffectiveDate]) AS [EffectiveDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [IM]) AS [IM], Convert(VarChar(250), [RevisionDate]) AS [RevisionDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountAddress]) AS [AccountAddress], Convert(VarChar(250), [LSOCode]) AS [LSOCode], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASONonASOBoth]) AS [ASONonASOBoth], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedicalYN]) AS [MedicalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [NonManagedCareYN]) AS [NonManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ManagedCareYN]) AS [ManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HRAYN]) AS [HRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedHRAYN]) AS [MedHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [LPHRAYN]) AS [LPHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthyFutYN]) AS [HealthyFutYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HAHRAYN]) AS [HAHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HSAYN]) AS [HSAYN], Convert(VarChar(25
0), [FSAHealthCare]) AS [FSAHealthCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSADependentCare]) AS [FSADependentCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [DentalYN]) AS [DentalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [TaftHartley]) AS [TaftHartley], Convert(VarChar(250), [ParameterComments]) AS [ParameterComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContact]) AS [MLRContact], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress1]) AS [MLRContactAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress2]) AS [MLRContactAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactCity]) AS [MLRContactCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactState]) AS [MLRContactState], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactZip]) AS [MLRContactZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthRiskAssessment]) AS [HealthRiskAssessment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaYN]) AS [ErisaYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanName]) AS [ErisaPlanName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanNumber]) AS [ErisaPlanNum
ber], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaAdministrator]) AS [ErisaAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaClaimAdministrator]) AS [ErisaClaimAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaCost]) AS [ErisaCost], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOB]) AS [ErisaEOB], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBName]) AS [ErisaEOBName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress1]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress2]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBCity]) AS [ErisaEOBCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBState]) AS [ErisaEOBState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBZip]) AS [ErisaEOBZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBPhone]) AS [ErisaEOBPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAName]) AS [ErisaPAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress1]) AS [ErisaPAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress2]) AS [ErisaPAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPACity]) AS [Eris
aPACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAState]) AS [ErisaPAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAZip]) AS [ErisaPAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAPhone]) AS [ErisaPAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAName]) AS [ErisaLAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress1]) AS [ErisaLAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress2]) AS [ErisaLAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLACity]) AS [ErisaLACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAState]) AS [ErisaLAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAZip]) AS [ErisaLAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAPhone]) AS [ErisaLAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ERISAComments]) AS [ERISAComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNApproval]) AS [CSNApproval], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNPPO]) AS [CSNPPO], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOAP]) AS [CSNOAP], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNSupplemental]) AS [CSNSupplemental], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNReplacement]) AS [CSNReplacement], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNType]) AS [CSNType], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNIL915]) AS [CSNNBNIL915], Convert(VarCh
ar(250), [CSNNBNPA910]) AS [CSNNBNPA910], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA911]) AS [CSNNBNPA911], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNFL918]) AS [CSNNBNFL918], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNCA915]) AS [CSNNBNCA915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNMA904]) AS [CSNNBNMA904], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOwnLogo]) AS [CSNOwnLogo], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNAllBranches]) AS [CSNNBNAllBranches], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNBranchComment]) AS [CSNNBNBranchComment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOStopLoss]) AS [ASOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOCigna]) AS [ASOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOThirdParty]) AS [ASOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASORetirees]) AS [ASORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOStopLoss]) AS [ISOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOCigna]) AS [ISOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOThirdParty]) AS [ISOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISORetirees]) AS [ISORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbCigna]) AS [ASOReimbCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbOther]) AS [ASOReimbOther]'



Declare @a table (pos int, rn int identity(1,1))
Declare @ct int = 0
Declare @pos int
Declare @oldpos int
Select @oldpos=0
select @pos=charindex(char(10),@var) 
while @ct <= (select len(@var) - len(replace(@var,char(10),'')))
    begin
    insert into @a Values (@pos)
    Select @oldpos=@pos
    select @pos=charindex(char(10),Substring(@var,@pos + 1,len(@var))) + @pos
    select @ct = @ct + 1
end

Select 
    --*,
    substring(@var,isnull(a2.pos,0),a1.pos) as SubSet
from @a a1
left join @a a2 on a2.rn  = a1.rn - 1


--edit for your comment...

select 
    --forces a CR at the comma before 950 characters 
    stuff(replace(@var,char(10),''),charindex('],',replace(@var,char(10),''),950),0,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking a string up when it's filled with table field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314803/breaking-a-string-up-when-its-filled-with-table-field-names)

Comment: Yes, I want to delete that one.

Comment: It's a duplicate and you are unclear from the start. You keep changing the question and requirements after you are unsatisfied. You profile says you're a sql server master but the questions aren't [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you need to [really learn how to ask a sql question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I felt I was pretty clear, but I re-worded it and re-asked because I could tell there was some confusion.  I think this version is pretty clear, and the other question has been deleted.

Comment: You first said break it at 1000. Then 950. Now it's ever 950.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [TPSYN]) AS [TPSYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [SureFitYN]) AS [SureFitYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], Convert(VarChar(250), [Account Name]) AS [Account Name], Convert(VarChar(250), [EffectiveDate]) AS [EffectiveDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [IM]) AS [IM], Convert(VarChar(250), [RevisionDate]) AS [RevisionDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountAddress]) AS [AccountAddress], Convert(VarChar(250), [LSOCode]) AS [LSOCode], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASONonASOBoth]) AS [ASONonASOBoth], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedicalYN]) AS [MedicalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [NonManagedCareYN]) AS [NonManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ManagedCareYN]) AS [ManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HRAYN]) AS [HRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedHRAYN]) AS [MedHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [LPHRAYN]) AS [LPHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthyFutYN]) AS [HealthyFutYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HAHRAYN]) AS [HAHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HSAYN]) AS [HSAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSAHealthCare]) AS [FSAHealthCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSADependentCare]) AS [FSADependentCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [DentalYN]) AS [DentalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [TaftHartley]) AS [TaftHartley], Convert(VarChar(250), [ParameterComments]) AS [ParameterComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContact]) AS [MLRContact], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress1]) AS [MLRContactAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress2]) AS [MLRContactAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactCity]) AS [MLRContactCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactState]) AS [MLRContactState], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactZip]) AS [MLRContactZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthRiskAssessment]) AS [HealthRiskAssessment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaYN]) AS [ErisaYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanName]) AS [ErisaPlanName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanNumber]) AS [ErisaPlanNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaAdministrator]) AS [ErisaAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaClaimAdministrator]) AS [ErisaClaimAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaCost]) AS [ErisaCost], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOB]) AS [ErisaEOB], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBName]) AS [ErisaEOBName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress1]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress2]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBCity]) AS [ErisaEOBCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBState]) AS [ErisaEOBState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBZip]) AS [ErisaEOBZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBPhone]) AS [ErisaEOBPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAName]) AS [ErisaPAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress1]) AS [ErisaPAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress2]) AS [ErisaPAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPACity]) AS [ErisaPACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAState]) AS [ErisaPAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAZip]) AS [ErisaPAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAPhone]) AS [ErisaPAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAName]) AS [ErisaLAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress1]) AS [ErisaLAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress2]) AS [ErisaLAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLACity]) AS [ErisaLACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAState]) AS [ErisaLAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAZip]) AS [ErisaLAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAPhone]) AS [ErisaLAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ERISAComments]) AS [ERISAComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNApproval]) AS [CSNApproval], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNPPO]) AS [CSNPPO], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOAP]) AS [CSNOAP], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNSupplemental]) AS [CSNSupplemental], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNReplacement]) AS [CSNReplacement], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNType]) AS [CSNType], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNIL915]) AS [CSNNBNIL915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA910]) AS [CSNNBNPA910], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA911]) AS [CSNNBNPA911], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNFL918]) AS [CSNNBNFL918], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNCA915]) AS [CSNNBNCA915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNMA904]) AS [CSNNBNMA904], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOwnLogo]) AS [CSNOwnLogo], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNAllBranches]) AS [CSNNBNAllBranches], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNBranchComment]) AS [CSNNBNBranchComment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOStopLoss]) AS [ASOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOCigna]) AS [ASOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOThirdParty]) AS [ASOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASORetirees]) AS [ASORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOStopLoss]) AS [ISOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOCigna]) AS [ISOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOThirdParty]) AS [ISOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISORetirees]) AS [ISORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbCigna]) AS [ASOReimbCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbOther]) AS [ASOReimbOther]'

;with cte as (
                Select *,Grp = sum(len(RetVal)-0) over (Order By RetSeq) /  950
                 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](replace(@S,'],','],|'),'|') 
)
Select S = replace(Stuff((Select '' +String + '|||'
    From (
            Select Grp
                  ,String = (Select Stuff((Select ' '+RetVal From cte Where Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
             From  (Select Distinct Grp From cte) A
          ) A
    Order by Grp
    For XML Path ('')),1,0,'') 
    ,'|||',char(13))
```

**Returns**

```
TransID, Convert(VarChar(250), [TPSYN]) AS [TPSYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [SureFitYN]) AS [SureFitYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountNbr]) AS [AccountNbr], Convert(VarChar(250), [Account Name]) AS [Account Name], Convert(VarChar(250), [EffectiveDate]) AS [EffectiveDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [IM]) AS [IM], Convert(VarChar(250), [RevisionDate]) AS [RevisionDate], Convert(VarChar(250), [AccountAddress]) AS [AccountAddress], Convert(VarChar(250), [LSOCode]) AS [LSOCode], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASONonASOBoth]) AS [ASONonASOBoth], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedicalYN]) AS [MedicalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [NonManagedCareYN]) AS [NonManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [ManagedCareYN]) AS [ManagedCareYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HRAYN]) AS [HRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [MedHRAYN]) AS [MedHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [LPHRAYN]) AS [LPHRAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthyFutYN]) AS [HealthyFutYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [HAHRAYN]) AS [HAHRAYN],
Convert(VarChar(250), [HSAYN]) AS [HSAYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSAHealthCare]) AS [FSAHealthCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [FSADependentCare]) AS [FSADependentCare], Convert(VarChar(250), [DentalYN]) AS [DentalYN], Convert(VarChar(250), [TaftHartley]) AS [TaftHartley], Convert(VarChar(250), [ParameterComments]) AS [ParameterComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContact]) AS [MLRContact], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress1]) AS [MLRContactAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactAddress2]) AS [MLRContactAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactCity]) AS [MLRContactCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactState]) AS [MLRContactState], Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRContactZip]) AS [MLRContactZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [HealthRiskAssessment]) AS [HealthRiskAssessment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaYN]) AS [ErisaYN],
Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanName]) AS [ErisaPlanName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanNumber]) AS [ErisaPlanNumber], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaAdministrator]) AS [ErisaAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaClaimAdministrator]) AS [ErisaClaimAdministrator], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaCost]) AS [ErisaCost], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOB]) AS [ErisaEOB], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBName]) AS [ErisaEOBName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress1]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBAddress2]) AS [ErisaEOBAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBCity]) AS [ErisaEOBCity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBState]) AS [ErisaEOBState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBZip]) AS [ErisaEOBZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaEOBPhone]) AS [ErisaEOBPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAName]) AS [ErisaPAName],
Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress1]) AS [ErisaPAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAAddress2]) AS [ErisaPAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPACity]) AS [ErisaPACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAState]) AS [ErisaPAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAZip]) AS [ErisaPAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPAPhone]) AS [ErisaPAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAName]) AS [ErisaLAName], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress1]) AS [ErisaLAAddress1], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAAddress2]) AS [ErisaLAAddress2], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLACity]) AS [ErisaLACity], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAState]) AS [ErisaLAState], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAZip]) AS [ErisaLAZip], Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaLAPhone]) AS [ErisaLAPhone], Convert(VarChar(250), [ERISAComments]) AS [ERISAComments], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNApproval]) AS [CSNApproval], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNPPO]) AS [CSNPPO], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOAP]) AS [CSNOAP],
Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNSupplemental]) AS [CSNSupplemental], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNReplacement]) AS [CSNReplacement], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNType]) AS [CSNType], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNIL915]) AS [CSNNBNIL915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA910]) AS [CSNNBNPA910], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNPA911]) AS [CSNNBNPA911], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNFL918]) AS [CSNNBNFL918], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNCA915]) AS [CSNNBNCA915], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNMA904]) AS [CSNNBNMA904], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNOwnLogo]) AS [CSNOwnLogo], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNAllBranches]) AS [CSNNBNAllBranches], Convert(VarChar(250), [CSNNBNBranchComment]) AS [CSNNBNBranchComment], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOStopLoss]) AS [ASOStopLoss], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOCigna]) AS [ASOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOThirdParty]) AS [ASOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASORetirees]) AS [ASORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOStopLoss]) AS [ISOStopLoss],
Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOCigna]) AS [ISOCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISOThirdParty]) AS [ISOThirdParty], Convert(VarChar(250), [ISORetirees]) AS [ISORetirees], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbCigna]) AS [ASOReimbCigna], Convert(VarChar(250), [ASOReimbOther]) AS [ASOReimbOther]
```

**The Parse UDF -- Can be INLINE if Needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

> **EDIT - INLINE Verserion (no need for the UDF)**

```
;with cte as (
                Select *,Grp = sum(len(RetVal)-0) over (Order By RetSeq) /  950
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(@S,'],','],|'),'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) A
)
Select S = replace(Stuff((Select '' +String + '|||'
    From (
            Select Grp
                  ,String = (Select Stuff((Select ' '+RetVal From cte Where Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
             From  (Select Distinct Grp From cte) A
          ) A
    Order by Grp
    For XML Path ('')),1,0,'') 
    ,'|||',char(13))
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm not running this correctly or understanding the output, but when I paste the output into Textpad I get everything on one line.  No line breaks at all.  I need line breaks approximately every 950 characters, depending on where the closest instance of "]," is.

Comment: I just updated the question to show what the resulting string should look like.

Comment: FRICKIN' BRILLIANT!  I went with the Inline version and it's spot on. 
 Thanks a ton!

Comment: @JohnnyBones Happy it helped :)

Comment: @JohnnyBones Just keep the Parse UDF in your back pocket.  You never know when you need a good splitter